# How to Shorten a lot of Repetition

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count

I am trying to make a game of Tic Tac Toe, and I ran into this problem.

I have to store a lot of different variables with very similar characters.
Currently, I have a solution, but it seems ineffective. I am trying to find a quicker and easier way of accomplishing the same task.

Below is a solution I currently have, but it seems like there is a lot of wasted space.

```
    p1 = playerX.count(1)
    p2 = playerX.count(2)
    p3 = playerX.count(3)
    p4 = playerX.count(4)
    p5 = playerX.count(5)
    p6 = playerX.count(6)
    p7 = playerX.count(7)
    p8 = playerX.count(8)
    p9 = playerX.count(9)
    c1 = computerO.count(1)
    c2 = computerO.count(2)
    c3 = computerO.count(3)
    c4 = computerO.count(4)
    c5 = computerO.count(5)
    c6 = computerO.count(6)
    c7 = computerO.count(7)
    c8 = computerO.count(8)
    c9 = computerO.count(9)
    # Player Win options
    if (p1  and p2  and p3 ) or (p1  and p4  and p7 ) or (p1  and p5  and p9 ) or (p2  and p5  and p8) or (p3 ==1 and p5  and p7 ) or (p3  and p6  and p9 ) or (p4  and p5  and p6) or (p7 and p8 and p9):
        winner = 1
    # AI Win options
    elif (c1  and c2  and c3 ) or (c1  and c4  and c7 ) or (c1  and c5  and c9 ) or (c2  and c5  and c8) or (c3 ==1 and c5  and c7 ) or (c3  and c6  and c9 ) or (c4  and c5  and c6) or (c7  and c8  and c9):
        winner = 2
    if winner == 1  or winner == 2:
        break
```

This basically checks all 8 ways of winning the game for the player and AI.
It works, but I am trying to find a way to shorted the assigning of variables.

A way I was thinking of doing this was by using a 'for loop'. But I am unsure how to make one that will accommodate it.

```
p = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
c = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    for i in p:
        p[i] = playerX.count(i)
        c[i] = computerO.count[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```python
c = []
p = []
for x in range(1,10):
    c.append(PlayerX.count(x))
    p.append(computer0.count(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried what you explained, and it worked, but not for what I was trying to do. I updated to post to explain further what I am trying to accomplish. Sorry for not doing so previously since it was not very expressive of what I was trying to accomplish.